# Does Testcafe have the capability to test Document PiP features?

Tags: testing, frontend, automated-tests, testcafe, picture-in-picture

Trying to create an automated test for a popup window (user clicks on a button then popup window opens) using testcafe however I keep getting errors saying I require user activation. I've gotten around this by manually clicking on the webpage but that leads to a "Opening a PiP window requires https or file protocol" error which I don't understand since testcafe loads my apps url with https. Any support/guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The TestCafe team will be happy to assist you with this issue. Please create a separate thread in the official TestCafe repository - use the following link: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml.

Also, refer to the following help topic before submitting the issue: [How to create a Minimal Working Example](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402636/faq/general-info#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue.)